# Slick Carousel: Adapt .slick-track to scaled image height in center mode

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

In a current project I am using Slick Carousel for the first time and in most aspects, it works quite well for me. But I have two open questions, one of which I want to post here. My Slick implementation works in center mode and scales the centered image via CSS:

```
&.slick-center {     
   transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

Now I want the height of the .slick-track to adapt to the largest slide (which slick does per default) multiplied by this factor (which it does not because it's a CSS transform), and I want Slick to do this with any given viewport. I managed to do it on initialization with:

```
$('.carousel').on('init', function(slick){
    var height = Math.ceil($(".pennants .slick-track").height()*1.4);
    $(".carousel .slick-track").css("height", height + 'px');
});
```

but that's as far as I got. Upon scaling, Slick falls back to the default height and cuts my centered slide. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to set height each time onBeforeChange, not sure